# Bootstrap 4 - keep columns with static width and no wrapping

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to get this layout working: Columns keep constant width when I resize the browser and they dont wrap - instead a horizontal scroll bar appears as soon as it reaches the min width. My code:

```
<div class="card card-outline-primary" style="min-width:500px">
<div class="card-block container-fixed">
    <form class="row">
        <div class="col-4" style="border:solid;border-color:red;border-width:5px;min-width:250px">
            <label for="visualTheme" class="control-label">1234</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" style="height:30px;width:200px" id="visualTheme" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4" style="border:solid;border-color:blue;border-width:5px;min-width:250px">
            <label class="control-label">5678</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" style="height:30px;width:200px" id="startingScreen" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4" style="border:solid;border-color:green;border-width:5px;min-width:250px">

        </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

And Fiddle:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnuogLgk/)

If I use min width for columns they wrap.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `flex-nowrap` class on the row..

```
<form class="row flex-nowrap"></form>
```